# Hearing the fellow next to you say the wrong prayer?

Tags: tefilla

If one happens to hear the person next to him saying vsain bracha when they are supposed to say vsain tal umatar l'bracha during the amidah and afterwards he finished the amidah he was told that he said the wrong insertion but he claims  that he said the correct nusach with certainty, who does he go by? Do we say that the person heard correct or the person that was actually saying the prayer is correct?

Comment: Why must we assume one way or the other. It is the subject who must decide what to do. Given all the facts, if he nevertheless believes he said the correct text, why should he act otherwise?

Comment: כל מלתא דלא רמיא על איניש לאו אדעתיה

Comment: @mevaqesh "It is the subject who must decide what to do" bring a source and thta would be an answer until then its just speculation

Comment: @DoubleAA , who should we apply that to? we can say that the person who heard him knew forsure since it threw him off his tefiilah,the guy actually davening might be davening by route ,so I am not sure how you want to apply כל מלתא דלא רמיא על איניש לאו אדעתיה

Comment: see kretot daf 12

Comment: rabbi Meir against Rabanan if I remember right